# will same variable name cause conflict in parfor

Tags: matlab, parfor

I have a basic code like this :

```
parfor i=1:8
    [t,y]=ode15s(@rate,tspan,cin,options,i); % the option i is evaluated in the rate function
    figure(1)
    subplot(3,3,i+1)
    plot(t,y)
    hold on
end
```

Will any conflict arise because the variable name `y` is same in all iterations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, every worker has its unique namespace.

However, a worker cannot open figures that display on the client (thanks for the reminder, @Edric), so everything after the call to `ode15s` will not produce any useful result.

To move the plotting outside the `parfor` loop, you can do the following (there are more efficient solutions, this one will work for sure):

```
tCell = cell(8,1);
yCell = cell(8,1);
parfor i=1:8
    [tCell{i},yCell{i}]=ode15s(@rate,tspan,cin,options,i); % the option i is evaluated in the rate function

end

figure(1)
for i=1:8
   subplot(3,3,i+1)
   plot(tCell{i},yCell{i})
   hold on
end
```

Comment: @Jonas just to be clear (and you probably already realise this) - workers cannot open figures **that display on the client**. They can open figures and then print to a file, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from @Jonas' answer, just a note to point out that if you're using R2013b or later, and you wish to display graphics while waiting for your parallel computations to complete, you could use [PARFEVAL](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/parfeval.html), like in this example: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/examples/parfeval-blackjack.html .

Comment: Neat - I wasn't aware of this feature (work still uses R2013a).